# mongoose pull from array based on value of object's property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find all documents whose `_id` exist in `idUpdates` , and then in those documents, there is an array named `closedBy`. This array contains objects of the following type:

```
{
   position: ObjectID,
   amount: Number
}
```

I then need to remove those objects who have position equal to a certain value (foundPosition._id).

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
await Position.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: idUpdates } },
        { $pull: { closedBy: { position: foundPosition._id } } }
      );
```

Comment: What is the type for `foundPosition._id`? Make sure you pass with `ObjectId` since your schema for `position` is an `ObjectId`.

Comment: @YongShun foundPosition._id is an ObjectId